# IndexedDB: Loading data from a JSON file when onUpgradeNeeded is called

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

My website has a JSON file containing data that is intended to be transferred into my users' local IndexedDB. I'm looking for a way to only load this JSON file when an update is actually needed.

To clarify, I plan for my website to run almost entirely off of my users' locally stored data whenever possible, similar to an app. They should only have to download the JSON file when a new IDB update is available.

So far, I've tried accomplishing this by running the `onUpgradeNeeded` event as an async function.

```js
if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB, which is required for most functions of this website. For the best support, please use the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.");
}

else {
  var dbVer = 39; //IDB Version (int only)
  var recipeObject; //instantiate global variable for module object import
  var recipeArray = []; //instantiate global array for module import
  var recipeDBver; //instantiate global variable for actual database version (TODO: implement version checking)
  var upgradeNeeded = false;
  var clearNeeded = false;
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open('recipeDatabase', dbVer);

  console.log("IDB.js running");

  openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
    console.log('Running onSuccess');
  };

  openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log('Open Request ERROR');
    console.dir(e);
  };

  openRequest.onupgradeneeded = async function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;

    console.log('Running onUpgradeNeeded');

    db.onerror = function(errorEvent) {
      console.log("onUpgradeNeeded ERROR");
      return;
    };

    importObject = await import("/resources/recipeDB.js");

    //TODO: remove debugging
    console.log('Module loaded');
    console.log(importObject);
    recipeObject = importObject.default;
    console.log(recipeObject);
    recipeDBver = recipeObject.recipeDBver;
    console.log(recipeDBver);
    recipeArray = recipeObject.recipeArray;
    console.log(recipeArray);

    upgradeNeeded = true;

    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('drinks')) {
      var storeOS = db.createObjectStore('drinks', {keyPath: 'id'});
      storeOS.createIndex('name', 'name', { unique: false });
      storeOS.createIndex('type', 'type', { unique: false });
      storeOS.createIndex('subtype', 'subtype', { unique: false });
      storeOS.createIndex('tags', 'tags', { unique: false });
    }
    else {
      clearNeeded = true;
    }

    console.log('IDB Upgrade Needed: ' + upgradeNeeded);
    console.log('IDB Clear Needed: ' + clearNeeded);
    db = e.target.result;
    if (clearNeeded == true) {
      clearData();
    }
    else if (upgradeNeeded == true) {
      for (var i = 0; i < recipeArray.length; i++) {
        addItem(recipeArray[i]);
      }
    }

  };


  function clearData() {

    var db = openRequest.result;

    var transaction = db.transaction(["drinks"], "readwrite");

    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("drinks");

    var objectStoreRequest = objectStore.clear();

    objectStoreRequest.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log('Error clearing data. ', e.target.error.name);
      console.dir(e);
    };

    objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
      console.log('Data cleared successfully.')
      for (var i = 0; i < recipeArray.length; i++) {
        addItem(recipeArray[i]);
      }
    };

  }

  function addItem(curItem) {
    var db = openRequest.result;
    var transaction = db.transaction(['drinks'], 'readwrite');
    var store = transaction.objectStore('drinks');
    var item = curItem;

    var request = store.add(item);

    request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log('Error', e.target.error.name);
      console.dir(e);
    };
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      console.log('Item added: ' + curItem.name);
    };
  }



}
```

The console returns the following:
[image: Console screenshot]

I'm assuming the `onUpgradeNeeded` event is timing out before the JSON file is able to load.

Is there a way to delay the timeout? If not, does anyone know of a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be seen from what you see in the console. First we get `IDB.js is running` and then you go into your `onupgradeneeded` handler, but then, instead of having anything from that function console logged, we immediately see the `onsuccess` handler run. The cause of this is because you defined your `onupgradeneeded` handler to be `async`, which means that this function essentially stops execution at the `await import("/resources/recipeDB.js");` line while it waits for the import to resolve. This essentially means as far as the IDB events are concerned that `onupgradeneeded` is done and it needs to go into the `onsuccess`. As Josh says above this is because `onupgradeneeded` needs to resolve *synchronously*.

What you can do to get around this, is:

- Make `onupgradeneeded` synchronous
- Update your IDB schema (create your new object store and indices)
- Import the data and upon successful import insert them into your database

This is one of the difficult things about using IndexedDB: it's not promised-based so using promised-based `async` functions doesn't always play well with it. I usually find these short-comings require more code to handle them (such as using `.then()` calls so that I can have synchronous event handlers while still doing necessary asynchronous activities).

Answer (score 1):

The onupgradeneeded event handler needs to complete synchronously. More accurately, requests upon/within the version change transaction that is running need to be started in the same tick of the event loop as when the version change transaction is started.

It is not clear from your question but it looks like you are making an async call to load the json and waiting for it to load, and this wait that happens is what allows the versionchange transaction to complete, and causes all requests made afterward to not occur in the same tick of the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1：Use javascript package json data.
Step 2：Use `importScript()` in upgrade event.
Step 3：Run your indexedDB script with `Worker`.